# Complex conjugate polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, z \mapsto \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k z^k$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_0$ a complex polynomial. Is then the complex conjugated $\overline{P}$ of $P$ again a polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomials are analytic. The conjugate of a non-constant
 analytic function is never analytic.  Look at the Cauchy-Riemann equation.

Comment: As is defined $P$ and $\bar{P}$ are not complex polynomials, but
are complex polynomial functions